# VBA Excel Passing an Button as Argument

Tags: excel, vba

I want to pass a CommandButton as an argument.

Example:

```
Sub calc(btn as button)
 btn.Caption = "Something"   
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 calc(CommandButton1)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 calc(CommandButton2)
End Sub
```

Is something like the above possible? If yes how can I do it?

*edit*

Thanks for your response, but I dont get it. So it looks like this now:

```
Public Sub calc(ByRef btn as Object)
 btn.Caption = "Something"   
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 calc(CommandButton1)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 calc(CommandButton2)
End Sub
```

Maybe someone can explain it to me in more detail, because Im very new to VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sub:

```
Public Sub temp(ByRef cmdb As Object)
cmdb.Caption = "somethine else"
End Sub
```

This is how you would call it

```
call sub (commandbutton_1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I dont get it. So it looks like this now:

    Public Sub calc(ByRef btn as Object)
     btn.Caption = "Something"   
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     calc(CommandButton1)
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
     calc(CommandButton2)
    End Sub

Maybe someone can explain it to me in more detail, because Im very new to VBA.

Comment: changed it a bit, but don't how much easier it could explain it :), If it still doesn't make sense email me your file and I can take a look at it for you

Comment: thank you very much! It works. I need to read some more about the Call keyword.

Comment: np, glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
Sub calc(btn As MSForms.CommandButton)
    btn.Caption = "Something"
End Sub
```

And you must invoke it following the rules:

```
 calc CommandButton1        // best

 call calc (CommandButton1) // ok but verbose

 calc (CommandButton1)      // type mismatch!
```

(The type mismatch is because the parentheses evaluate `CommandButton1` which results in its default property (a string) which is incompatible with the method argument type)